# How to find explicit formula for a family of polynomials defined by $f_0(x)=0$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=(xf_n(x)+1)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

So I have a family of polynomials defined as $$f_0(x)=0$$ $$f_{n+1}(x)=(xf_n(x)+1)^2$$ for $n\geq 0$.
I am wondering if and how I would find the explicit formula for $f_n(x).$

I tried listing out the first couple of functions $$\begin{align}
f_0(x)&=0 \\
f_1(x)&=1 \\
f_2(x)&=(x+1)^2 \\
f_3(x)&=(x(x+1)^2+1)^2 \\
f_4(x)&=(x(x(x+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2
\end{align}$$ and so on. It is clear from this that the degree of $f_n(x)$ is $2^n-2$.

However, I am having difficulty determining the coefficients. Trivially, the first and last coefficients are both $1$. Perhaps through Vieta's formulas we can determine other coefficients like the coefficient of the $2$nd term, but I don't see a clear way to get other coefficients/terms.

After doing an OEIS search, I discovered that the coefficients line up exactly with [A202019](https://oeis.org/A202019). Figuring out why...

Comment: One possible way to get started is by finding the coefficients for the first few by hand and checking if the OEIS (https://oeis.org/) has anything to say. (see examples of how to enter a sequence of polynomials here: https://oeis.org/search?q=polynomial+coefficients&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Comment: Why are you interested in this sequence? What makes you think there's a nice description about it?

Comment: Calvin Lin: Interestingly, the coefficients happen to fall exactly in line with A202019 (https://oeis.org/A202019).

Answer (score 1):

There is no known formula for such sequence. However there's something that can be said about some coefficients:

For $m<n$, the coefficient of $x^m$ in $f_n(x)$ is $C_{m+1}$, the ${(m+1)}$-th Catalan number.

Comment: Ah, so in the limit, $n\to \infty,$ the function $f_{\infty}(x)=C_1+C_2x+C_3x^2+\cdots.$